# DVD burner is recognized by Windows, but not by software

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, dvd-burning

- OS: Windows Vista x64
- DVD-RW: Pioneer DVD-RW DVR-219L ATA Device

I can burn DVD images by Windows Explorer, but both SCDWriter and CDBurnerXP doesn't show the device as possible burner. I've checked its drivers via Windows Device Manager, it says no new drivers needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the following program:

> RAID: Intel® Rapid Storage Technology Driver for Intel Desktop Boards
>   http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?lang=eng&changeLang=true&DwnldId=20984

has fixed my problem.